# Protecting handmade electronics from accidental water spillings

Tags: diodes, keyboard, teensy, waterproof

Keep in mind that I dont know the least about electronics. I have soldered and used some arduinos before, but that is it.

I am preparing to make a mechanical keyboard (or handwire like they say on /r/mk) and the common solution for registering keys is a [diode matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_matrix_circuit), which will be connected to a teensy board, under a custom-designed aluminum case.

But how can one protect this kind of structure from spillings ?
What component, precisely, is vulnerable to water ? Pcbs are is'nt it ? so this mainly applies to the teensy ?

If that is true, would encasing the teensy solve the problem ?

Maybe water would make some component rust, like the case, or the diodes' anodes and cathodes.(Though aluminum should not be damaged by some water i guess)

That makes me realise there should be plural types of damages occasioned, so what other damages would a water or a coffee spilling do on my keyboard, and how can i protect it ? and of course, how much would it cost ?

Comment: have you got waterproof switches under the keys? or are you going to use a waterproof membrand above the switches?

Comment: I am not going to use either, but I must admin I didn't know about waterproofs switches. I'm looking into it right now, that does seem like an idea.

Comment: some switches are really hard to dry out if they get wet. if you wake your circuit board and switch array dishwasher safe, food spills should not be big permanent problem.

Comment: How do I make them dishwasher safe ? I guess I first have to find water-resilient switches ? Or I take regular switches, then open them and re-lube them ?

Comment: Keyboards are quite cheap. Just replace it.

Comment: @LeonHeller I am talking about making (a quite expensive) one, and I am trying to see if I can make it more resilient before finishing my plans.

Comment: You concern should be the keyswitches more than the electronics.  MCU circuitry of the type you describe can be washed if contaminated - the goal is to get it clean before it dries.  But key switches are more challenging to clean and dry.  Ideally plan things so you can disassemble the keytops and framing for cleaning, and perhaps even replace individual switches on the board.  Note that if you do fully clean keys in a way that degreases them, the more complex elements like space bar, control keys, etc may require a suitable grease before they will work smoothly again.

Comment: @ChrisStratton How can I connect the pins of the [switches](https://www.riecktron.co.za/en/image/cache/data/products/13834-03-600x600.jpg) without soldering them to a diode matrix ? Or what other solution for replacement exist ?

Comment: Soldering does not mean something cannot be replaced, *especially* if you are willing to cut up the plastic housing of the old component to ease removal.

Comment: That makes sense, but I was kinda scared the whole structure would be weaker after a couple operations (if ever). Just in case you don't know what the final thing might look like, [here is one](https://imgur.com/a/Y828u) (a really clean one, by /r/mk's say). So you think that can be cut, replaced and resoldered ? Would there be more convenient solutions ? (maybe placeholders for the switches or something like that ?)

Comment: If you are doing point-to-point wiring replacement should be trivial - you have none of the challenges of getting something off the board or damaging traces - worst case if you somehow damage a neighbor you have to replace that too.  Your larger challenge will be that *mechanical* holding frame.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73341/discussion-between-pierre-antoine-guillaume-and-chris-stratton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is current under water, there is electroylsis, and that causes corrosion. YouTuber GreatScott (highly recommended) has 2 videos:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGLUsQozT94
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8ycmroFQSs

They are basically the answer to your question.